# Replace text input value with whatever is typed inside

Tags: jquery, html, forms, codeigniter, input

I've made an update form for my projects on my site. In my php, I populate the values of the input text tags with the existing information from the database. I want to be able to change the value of the input tags to whatever I type, but doesn't seem to be working. When I hit submit, the values don't change at all (I checked my database, the fields' values are the same as before).

I feel like this is a really straightforward idea, basically any WYSIWYG/CMS functions the same. What am I doing wrong? What Javascript/jQuery might I need to accomplish this?

**(Oops) Here's My Code**

(I'm using CodeIgniter) Here's my PHP for the input tag:

```
<?php 
    $title_input = array(
        'name' => 'title',
        'id' => 'title',
        'autocomplete' => 'off'
    );

    if (isset($updating)) {
        $title_input['value'] = $project->title;
    }
    echo form_input($title_input);
?>
```

Which spits out:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="My Project Title" id="title" autocomplete="off">
```

When the form is submitted, this is how I (try to) change the info in the database:

```
$project->title = $this->input->post('title');
```

It's the exact same code I use for when I create a NEW project, except I was hoping that it would detect the changed input text value. :/

Comment: post code dat u tried ..

Comment: SHOW YOUR CODE! Hopefully the caps lock will make you see the comment.

Comment: What are you using to read & process the submitted form? Sounds like, instead of getting the values from the form, you're still reading it from the database, so naturally, it never changes.

Comment: Hard to know why your data is not making it to your DB without seeing your controller and model.  Also, why not use the form helper and set_value to conditionally set the value based on the value in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

I have a page currently that takes input and stores it in the database and when the page is revisited, if there is any information previously stored, it is loaded and can be edited. upon submit, I save again.

Things you should consider:

- Ensure you are checking $_POST in the function handling the update. If you are using too separate functions(for new and for update) then use echo statement to check that all if statements parameters are valid and not empty).
- Use isset as much as you can with combination of != '' and this will make sure if statement is correctly evaluated.
- Maintain a separate model function to handle update. Best thing to do imho is to save the whole form again. Do not only check for modified fields. You can check for required fields not to be set empty but other than that, resubmit the whole form if possible

More assistance could be provided if you willing to share your code